# Difference between "Live" and "Define"

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

In many mathematical text to determine an object on manifold, the verbs "live" and "define" are used.

I'm interested to know whether there is a difference between the concepts of "to define" and "to live"?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: certainly you mean 'let' and 'define'..natural languages are rather lax, so they could mean the same thing or not, depending on the author..personally, 'let' means i'm choosing or restricting a symbol (i.e. a variable, a function, a set, etc), while 'define' is reserved for 'static' definitions (usually of functions or sets that are meant to stay the same from that point on)

Comment: @suissidle The word `let` sometimes used as `define` but informally. What's more, it sometimes used as `assign`, e.g. let $x=0,y=1$.

Comment: well said..in that case, $x$ is often a dummy variable that has already been given a certain range

Comment: Considering the tags, it may well be that "live" was intended. There are statements like "This surface is defined in $\mathbb R^3$." and "This surface lives in $\mathbb R^3$." @Bakhoda, is this the sort of use you're asking about? If not, please give examples of the kind of use you mean.

Comment: @joriki, what I want is exactly the examples that you used.

Answer (score 5):

Considering Joriki's example

> This surface lives in $\mathbb R^3$.

the important thing to be aware of is that this is a **informal and deliberately imprecise** way of speaking. It should never be used to *provide any new information* (unless you're more than usually sure that whomever you're speaking to will understand it as you mean it), but can be used to *call attention to* something you already know, or to suggest a way to *visualize* what you're speaking about. It certainly has no place in a written-down proof or definition, but might be used in informal motivation and explanations.

In general, the content of "$X$ lives in $Y$" is that $X$ is an element of $Y$, or a subset of $Y$ or a function on $Y$, or sometimes even a function with *values* in $Y$, (such as a parameterized path in $Y$), or ... something like that. In general it invites you to think of $X$ as something that "takes place" inside $Y$ in some appropriate sense. It's up to the listener to imagine *which* appropriate sense is meaningful in the context, but there's a strong subtext that the exact technical nature of the relation between $X$ and $Y$ will not be of paramount importance for understanding what comes next.

(In the particular example above, the meaning is almost certainly that the surface is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$ and is equipped with the subset topology (or metric) it inherits from the standard topology (or metric) on $\mathbb R^3$).